# SQL Server 2012 : Installing on D:

Tags: installation, sql-server-2012

i am trying to install SQL Server 2012 
i choose D: for everything but still it told me during installation itself
that it's going to install config file on C:
following is the path
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20121117_151400\ConfigurationFile.ini

i was like ok maybe it's just log and stuff

but then when i look at
C:\Program Files 
it also created

1. MS Visual Studio 10.0
2. MS Analysis Services
3. MS Help Viewer
4. MS SQL Server
5. Microsoft .NET

How can i install everything on D:?

Regards